# bs-tooltip TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

My controller looks like this

```
$scope.showSelectedComp = function($event, fuse_id, index) {
    var compTooltip = $tooltip($event.target, {title: 'My Title', contentTemplate:'views/compTooltip.html'});

}
```

And my view looks like this

```
<p ng-mouseover="showSelectedComp($event, fuse_id, $index)">12</p>
```

When I hover over the element I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js:9:25995)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the above call to $tooltip to this:

```
$tooltip(angular.element($event.target), fuse_id, index)
```

Your problem is that the element returned in the target is not a jQuery/jQlite element hence it can't find the node name.